# PyMuPdf - missing addPage(page) method

Tags: python-3.x, pymupdf

i used PyPDF2 before and i wrote this class

```
class pdfWriter:
  fh = None
  pdf_obj = None

  def __init__(self, path):
    if(not path.endswith('.pdf')):
        path += ".pdf"
    self.fh = open(path, 'wb')
    self.pdf_obj = PdfFileWriter()

  def addPage(self, page):
    self.pdf_obj.addPage(page)

  def write(self):
    self.pdf_obj.write(self.fh)
```

now i'm trying to achieve the same thing using PyMuPdf but i can't find a method to add a page object to a document object.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: an index-based way could be `new_doc.insert_pdf(doc, from_page=page.number + offset, to_page=page.number + offset)`

Answer (score 1):

Do this: `page = doc.newPage()` and you are done.
There are parameters letting you choose the desired page size and also the location if the PDF already contains pages.